# How do I get rid of the Norton Download Manager that keeps popping up?

Tags: norton-antivirus

I have uninstalled Norton using several methods and I still have the Norton Download Manager popping up.  I want to get rid of Norton completely.  I have tried the Norton Utilities, I have tried MS-Config.  Nothing works.

Comment: If you are getting this message "Install an updated version of your Norton product for Windows 10", [go to this page](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v113935352_EndUserProfile_en_us)

Comment: I have this problem as well.  I've tried all the provided answers and none of them work for me.  The NDM seems to be deeply embedded in my copy of Windows 10, and Symantec is unable or unwilling to help me.

Answer (score 4):

check to make sure it isn't in your public folders... I searched and researched, I went into the registries, deleted all norton products in the registry keys as well as in windows currentversion run & runonce (if it in there) and then discovered when I deleted it from the runonce folder within the registry under microsoft windows for local user, I saw the window pop right back up and the key automatically reappear after I just deleted... that is when I SAW where the program was hiding... it was hiding under user\public\downloads (or public downloads). I deleted it from there, and then went back to the registry and deleted it from the keys again that reproduced themselves.

Then I went to downloads just for me (being I'm the only one that uses my laptop) and removed any other downloads from norton (such as the "removal tool") just to be certain.

After that I restarted my computer and so far... I haven't seen anymore splash screens for installing norton...

Comment: Could you clarify, what is "user\public\downloads"? Are you talking about the registry or the disk?

Answer (score 4):

I had a client with same issue. I used Norton's removal tool and manually deleted every reference. Still had pop up every time computer booted up until figured out this...

After doing everything listed, if you are still getting the pop ups and reminders, this should take care of it. There is a folder that remains buried in `C:\Users\[Primary User's Name]\AppData\Local\Temp` folder. It just has a long string of letters and numbers. If you double click and go into it you will see the icons for the pop up message. Go out of folder, delete, and empty trash can. Reboot computer and you should be rid of this nuisance.

Comment: I found the folder, deleted it, and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete Norton files (shortcuts) from desktop.
2. Perform a un-install from control panel for Norton.
3. Highlight the following Norton Folder located at c:\users\public\publicdownloads\norton
4. Delete the folder Norton and send to the recycle bin.

After completing all of the above, reboot your computer and the file should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a few days back. [Here's my question and the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1036969/how-to-prevent-files-in-public-folder-c-users-public-from-regenerating/1037081#1037081).

The link should be enough to answer your question, but in case it becomes broken in the future, here's my version of the answer:

1. Go into Control Panel, and check the list of installed applications on your computer. If you see anything to do with Norton/Symantec, uninstall it.
2. Download and install [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902). Open the program and wait for it to generate entries for all startup programs (this is a MUCH more comprehensive list than the one in Task Manager). Scroll through the list and uncheck any Norton/Symantec entries that you find.

**Optional (Autoruns should be enough to solve the problem, but I would do this just in case):**

Manually delete all Norton files on your system by searching for "Norton" at the C: level in your file system. Delete any Norton files that show up. Also do the same with Norton registry keys - open `regedit.exe` and click through all the lists until you find something to do with Norton. If you find anything to do with it, delete.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\AV\Norton Antivirus` is where the updater lives

Answer (score 0):

When the installer pops up, open task manager and find .exe file that has been running it and delete it. Also go ahead and delete the file named SymInstallStub.exe which runs Norton Utilities Installer, that's why the installer always pops up. I believe it accidently came with the Adobe Shockwave but anyways after that, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides a tool that you will need to download to fully remove the product.

[Norton Clean Uninstall](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v113935352)

This may be a more direct link for Windows users, a restart is required after the process completes...

[For windows users, Mac link also](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v60392881)

Answer (score 0):

The Norton installation folder and the exe file with the arrow that keeps replicating themselves

1. Right click on them one at a time
2. go to properties and then
   open the files location
3. Delete all those folders they contain
   scrips,registry keys etc. be sure to also delete the folder that
   contained these files check the address bar for the location.Repeat
   with the second file folder
4. Run spy/malware scan/clean Done!!

Answer (score 0):

Close from task manager, search for it in windows explorer right click "open file location" right click on the shortcut then press "open file location" shift+rightclick "delete"

Answer (score 0):

I tried a mixture of @Chezshea's and @SeaChele's answers and it worked for me. First, open Resource Monitor (*not* Performance Monitor) and there (under the CPU section) you'll find `FSDUI_Custom.exe` running. That's the culprit. First end that process tree, by right-clicking on the process and then clicking "End Process Tree". Then, you need to find and delete all folders containing `FSDUI_Custom.exe` and other related files. For me, there were three places to look:

1. There is a folder on my desktop whose name looks like `{DSP-N360-22211151-SHPD-FSD5250006}`. Delete that folder.
2. A folder with the same (or similar) name under `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\Temp`. Delete that folder.
3. Most importantly, a folder with the same name under `C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Norton`. Just delete that whole folder, `C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Norton`.

Deleting all of these should stop them from regenerating each other. Note that **you must first end the process tree `FSDUI_Custom.exe`**, else you won't be able to delete some of the folders above, since they would contain a process that is running. This worked for me.

Norton isn't "antivirus"; **it is the virus**. I mean, *it literally replicates itself on your computer*, and makes it extremely difficult to remove. It installs a crypto miner without the user's knowledge. It's the biggest piece of shit I've ever seen, and I can't believe I've been stupid enough to pay and subscribe to it for many years now.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and is more proof of how Norton has become a joke (eg. trying to sell you the extras on every scan, to many pop ups with these adverts and too mnay that got annoying when I was using dodgy sites to watch free TV that is why I pay for Internet security! After reading all this, I got rang Norton and got them to sort it for me, was quicker as they answered straight away. The Norton guy removed it from the Backgorund Processes section in the Processes tab of Task Manager and removed any Norton apps still in C:\Program Files / (\86). Have restarted and it seems fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).