# How to prevent files in Public Folder (C:\Users\Public) from regenerating?

Tags: windows-10, public-folders, norton-antivirus

I recently upgraded to Windows 10, and it's been great, except for one problem with the Public folder. There's a Norton Update Mangager file **(FSDUI_NAV.exe)** in the Public folder that keeps popping up and telling me that my current Norton installation isn't compatible with Windows 10, and that I should update Norton.

Well, the thing is, I uninstalled Norton right before upgrading to Windows 10, and moved to BitDefender... so I have no idea why this Norton file is still there.

I have tried deleting the "Norton" folder under "Public" multiple times, but every few minutes or so, **it regenerates, and the FSDUI_NAV.exe program pops up again.**

So my question is, how do I permanently remove the "Norton" folder and its contents from "Public", and thus keep the message from popping up?

Thank you.

Comment: Just use the Norton Removal tool.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I used the tool, and the program still keeps popping up. I even deleted every Norton file I could find on my file system, including the folder under Public. The folder keeps regenerating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some Norton components on your machine, that re-installs these files. First check whether any Norton package is still listed in your installed applications and uninstall it.

If you can't find anything there, use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to find (use the filter) any Norton entries on your computer and disable them.

If you can't find any Norton entries there, you need to find out which process it adding these files back, use: [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to do this. Set a filter on `C:\users\public`

Comment: I see numerous "FSDUI_NAV.exe" entries in the Process Monitor. That's the name of the program that keeps popping up - what should I do with it? And how do I set a filter on `C:\Users\Public`? All I see are processes; no files/folders.

Comment: @AAA - from the Filter menu, use Filter... select `Path`, `begins with` `C:\Users\Public` or right click an existing path to include it.

Comment: Thank you. After setting the filter, I see "FSDUI_NAV.exe", which is the Norton Download Manager, "csrss.exe", and "RuntimeBroker.exe". So the process adding the Norton entries is likely FSDUI_NAV.exe?

Comment: I guess, the other two are valid Windows processes.

Comment: So what do I do with FSDUI_NAV.exe?

Comment: @AAA - Uninstall that Norton Download manager, if you don't want it. If no longer listed in the listed installed applications, find the files and remove them manually. Or use Autoruns to disable it.

Comment: It's looking good! I disabled the program with Autorun about 2 hours back, on top of manually deleting all Norton files/registry keys. The message hasn't popped up since, and considering it used to come up every 10 minutes or so, I'm confident that the problem is solved. Thanks very much for your help.